# " AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'edit' " discord.py error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As the title says I get the **"  AttributeError: 'User' object  has no attribute 'edit' "** error
MY Code is :

```
async def mute_user(ctx):
 user = client.get_user(339813312625901579)
 await user.edit(mute=True)
```

*(I use my ID just so i can test the bot)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` does not have `edit`, but [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit) does.

Change your command to take as input a discord Member. You can then use the passed `Member` object to mute the account. This does require that you have `import discord` in your code. Assuming your bot prefix is `!`, usage would be `!mute_user @name_of_user`.

```
async def mute_user(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.edit(mute=True)
```